# Create wifi tethering Hotspot in Android Marshmallow, without intervention?

Tags: android-6.0-marshmallow, hotspot

In Android M, I used code in [How to create wifi tethering Hotspot in Android Marshmallow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34172369/how-to-create-wifi-tethering-hotspot-in-android-marshmallow) to create hotspot, but it is not working.

I get error.:

> java.lang.SecurityException: android.tutorial.hotspotcreation was not granted  either of these permissions: android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE, android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS.

If I use that hotspot code.

The recommended way, is to use an intent:

```
startActivity(new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK));
```

Is there a way to create hotspot via code, without user-intervention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your error message clearly shows, you will have to add two permissions to your Manifest (or ask for them interactively on 6.0+):

- CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE
- WRITE_SETTINGS

Comment: Hi, I added both permissions and the code still gives error.

Comment: Which Android Version are you running on? Please provide your new error message.

Comment: Android 6.0.1 - exact error message - java.lang.SecurityException: android.tutorial.hotspotcreation was not granted either of these permissions: android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE, android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS., even with this permission inside AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: On Android 6.0 you have to implement runtime permissions!

Comment: only WRITE_SETTING to implement because it is only considered dangerous